# Sonata media context ignored

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I have defined new profile context in sonata_media.yaml:

```
    ...
    default_context: profile
    contexts:
        default:
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.dailymotion
                - sonata.media.provider.youtube
                - sonata.media.provider.image
                - sonata.media.provider.file
                - sonata.media.provider.vimeo
            formats:
                small: {width: 100, quality: 70}
                big:   {width: 500, quality: 70}
        profile:
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.image
            formats:
                small: {width: 90, quality: 70}
                big:   {width: 90, quality: 70}
    ...
```

In my admin class, it's called like this:

```
        $formMapper
            ->tab('User')
                ...
                ->with('Media')
                    ->add('profilePicture', MediaType::class, [
                        'provider' => 'sonata.media.provider.image',
                        'context'  => 'profile',
                        'required' => false,
                    ])
                ->end()
```

But when image is uploaded, thumbnails are generated in default context folder and dimensions.

There is no error.

Running `bin/console sonata:media:fix-media-context` doesn't help.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6SWp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Haha, I found, when an image is uploaded each new upload is done within the same context.
I just had to remove picture before upload and my new context is used :)
Maybe this post can help another newbie...